# how to connect to wlst command from java client?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, oracle11g, wlst

I'm using OBIEE for report. 
on server: i run successfully after execute: . ./setWLSEnv.sh,
and then java JavaTestWLST  -->ok successfull
but when i run on client by eclipse IDE then it has a problem following:
Exception:java.lang.RuntimeException: error in finding weblogic.Home
please show me the config and the step to do

Comment: my lib folder: com.bea.core.xml.xmlbeans_2.2.0.0.jar
com.oracle.cie.comdev_6.4.0.0.jar
com.oracle.cie.config-wls-schema_10.3.6.0.jar
com.oracle.cie.config-wls_7.2.0.0.jar
com.oracle.cie.config_7.2.0.0.jar
com.oracle.cie.wizard_6.1.0.0.jar
com.oracle.core.weblogic.msgcat_1.2.0.0.jar
jython.jar
weblogic.jar
wlfullclient.jar

Comment: private static InteractiveInterpreter interpreter=null;interpreter=new WLSTInterpreter(); // error' here: Exception:java.lang.RuntimeException: error in finding weblogic.Home